# Translate multiple fields per record into multiple records and a single field

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to convert multiple fields per record (in this case three fields) into a single field over multiple records.  For example, if the schema is

```
 userId, timestamp, field1, field2, field3
```

I'd like to convert that into

```
 userId, timestamp, field
```

e.g.

```
 abc123, 12:00:00, dog, dog, bird
 abc789, 12:00:01, wolf, sheep, horse
```

would become

```
 abc123, 12:00:00, dog
 abc123, 12:00:00, dog
 abc123, 12:00:00, bird
 abc789, 12:00:00, wolf
 abc789, 12:00:00, sheep
 abc789, 12:00:00, horse
```

The ordering doesn't matter

This is because the data for these fields was captured in parallel, but I want to be able to count the number of times particular values in those field show up regardless of whether they're in field1, field2, or field3. Specifically, I'd like to be able to count 2 dogs, 1, bird, 1, wolf, 1, sheep, and 1 horse.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So what you've tried so far?

Comment: I don't really have any idea where to start.

Comment: see my answer - isnt this good start for you? :o)

Comment: haha I hadn't noticed it! Thanks! It worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for BigQuery Legacy SQL:

```
SELECT 
  userId, 
  timestamp, 
  SPLIT(CONCAT(field1, ',', field2, ',', field3)) AS field 
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: Cool solution! I used Unions and ended up with a huge query, this was way better.

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, you can achieve this using [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/) (uncheck the "Use Legacy SQL" box under "Show Options") with an array literal; no need to concatenate and then split. For example,

```
SELECT
  userId,
  timestamp,
  [field1, field2, field3] AS field 
FROM YourTable;
```